# How to build a helloworld app in vue native?

Tags: android, vue.js, vue-native

I've setup a blank app and successfully running in android emulator using the following commands

```
npm install -g vue-native-cli
vue-native init test1 // Initializes crna project
cd test1

npm start
```

In http://localhost:19002/, i click "Run on Android device/emulator", the expo show the blank app "Open up App.js to start working on your app!"

I saw there is a helloworld app
https://vue-native.io/getting-started.html

but the above link didn't mention app.js, so i don't understand how to get start to  build a helloworld app.

Anyone knows what's am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You must replace the **app.js** with **app.vue**. Your folder must look something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaAaU.png.

Comment: tried alreay, i think i have this bug, but i can't resolve
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core/issues/87